# Bootstrap 4 change dynamic height cards order from different rows and columns

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am new at Bootstrap 4 and trying to find out how order classes work. I have this layout which includes

```
ROW 1:
COL-MD-4 with 3 cards inside
COL-MD-8 with 2 cards inside
ROW 2:
COL-MD-12 with 1 card inside
```

```
 ________   ____________________________
|DIV1    | |DIV4                        |
|ROW1    | |ROW1                        |
|COL-MD-4| |COL-MD-8                    |
|CARD    | |CARD                        |
|        |  ----------------------------
|        |  ____________________________
|        | |DIV5                        |
|        | |ROW1                        |
|        | |COL-MD-8                    |
|        | |CARD                        |
 --------  |                            |
 ________  |                            |
|DIV2    | |                            |
|ROW1    | |                            |
|COL-MD-4| |                            |
|CARD    | |                            |
 --------  |                            |
 ________  |                            |
|DIV3    | |                            |
|ROW1    | |                            |
|COL-MD-4| |                            |
|CARD    | |                            |
|        | |                            |
|        | |                            |
 --------   ----------------------------
 _______________________________________
|DIV6                                   |
|ROW2                                   |
|COL-12                                 |
|CARD                                   |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
 ---------------------------------------
```

And i am trying on mobile devices layout to change the order of divs. All divs will be COL-12 but I want the order to be DIV4, DIV1, DIV5, DIV6, DIV2, DIV3.
On -MD size and above the DIV5 should be flex:1 to match the lower limit of DIV3, this is why I created another row for DIV6. If there is another way to accomplish all that, I would be happy to learn how to do it!

Thanks

[**JSfiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/MerNion/m06pjxvr/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not clearly stated in the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#order-classes) the order classes appear only to apply to sibling columns within the same parent row. You can utilize `.order-last.order-md-first` on the first column to put "DIV2" & "DIV3" last on mobile.

In order to meet your constraints of re-ordering "DIV1" into another column you will instead need to have two instances of "DIV1" using different display classes (`.d-none.d-md-block` & `.d-md-none`) to toggle visibility.

Here is [my fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chan_omega/rzyLpq7g/) to demonstrate.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try it and let you know!